# Does there exists a closed proper subset of a bounded interval with the same measure as the interval?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Does there exists a closed set $C \subset [a, b]$ such that $\mu(C) = b - a$?

I keep thinking some argument based on summing over a finite union of disjoint intervals, letting $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ would work but I know that $[0,1]$ cannot be written as disjoint union of closed sets.

NOTE: $\subset$ denotes a proper subset.

Comment: If a point $p$ is in $[a,b]$ but not in $C$, some interval misses $C$.

Comment: No. The best you can do is a "fat" Cantor Set. You can adjust such a set to have a measure $\mu$, with $0\le\mu\lt b-a-\epsilon$, for any $\epsilon>0$ but not exactly $b-a$.

Comment: Yes so that fails since we cannot cover the interval with closed sets, but we can almost cover it with $F_{\sigma}$ sets.  Could that be closed?

Comment: Whatever it is, any $F_\sigma$ cover will dually correspond to some $G_\delta$ Cantor decomposition and you know that a Cantor decomposition is a primitive topologically (i.e. you either end up with a Cantor set or one of its subsets no matter what decomp you use). Therefore, since you can't do it with a Cantor decomposition, you can't do it at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider $U = [a, b]\setminus C$. As $C$ is closed, $U$ is open, and as $C$ is a proper subset of $[a, b]$, $U$ is non-empty so let $x \in U$. If $x \in (a, b)$, then as $U$ is open, there is an open interval $I$ containing $x$ with $I \subseteq U$. But then

$$\mu(C) = \mu([a, b]\setminus U) = \mu([a, b]) - \mu(U) = b - a - \mu(U) \leq b - a - \mu(I) < b - a$$ as $\mu(I) > 0$.

The argument above still works if $x = a$ or $x = b$, you just have to take $I$ to be of the form $[a, a + \varepsilon)$ or $(b - \varepsilon, b]$ respectively.

The general principle is that open non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ necessarily have positive Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 3):

If a point $p$ is in $[a,b]$ but not in $C$, then there is a subinterval of $[a,b]$ that is not contained in $C$. So $C$ must have measure less than $b-a$.